# How to overlay a view on top of an Activity?

Tags: android, android-activity, view, android-context

Is there a way to add a View dynamically on top of the current Activity's view?  One thing to note is this needs to be done from another class which only has access to the Activity's context.

ex:

```
public class ActivityClass extends Activity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        …       

        PopupClass popup = new PopupClass(this);
        popup.showPopup();
    }

}


public class PopupClass
{
    Context context;

    void Popup(Context ctx)
    {
        context = ctx;
    }

    void showPopup()
    {
        // Add a view on top of the current Activity.
    }
}
```

Is there a way for PopupClass to be able to add a view to the current Activity with just knowing the context?

PopupClass does not know anything else about the Activity nor can it pass back the View to ActivityClass for ActivityClass to add.

Comment: What sort of 'view' do you want PopupClass to add to ActivityClass?

Comment: It'd be a banner that would do something when clicked.  So pretty much a View with a background drawable set to an image, and also have a clickListener associated with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use custom Dialog's for this.

http://www.androidpeople.com/android-custom-dialog-example

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-display-custom-dialog-your-android-application

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I don't think this solves the issue.  The Dialog example is an activity which would block the current Activity.  The current Activity should retain focus and just add the new View onto it.

Comment: A dialog does cover up an activity, but it doesn't prevent an Activity's code from executing. If you don't want anything to cover up your activity then your only solution is to assign an ID to your layout and programmatically update the view. This is messy though and makes it harder to maintain your view. For an example, please see: http://technicalmumbojumbo.wordpress.com/2011/12/08/android-tutorial-series-layout/

Comment: In that wordpress tutorial look for the line `For programmatic implementation refer to the LinearLayoutActivity class below` and he shows you how to create a layout programmatically from scratch. However, since you already have a layout (you just want to tweak it), assign an ID to the layout in your XML, then use `findViewById()` in your activity to get a reference to the layout. Then, just like in the tutorial, programmatically create the widgets. When the widgets are ready, use layout.addView(widget)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using relative layouts for that purpose.
I guess you can also use frame layouts.
Take a look here:
http://www.learn-android.com/2010/01/05/android-layout-tutorial/5/

Answer (score 0):

Why not make PopClass extend Activity and in the AndroidManifest.xml attributes for the PopupClass activity, set `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"`

Then in ActivityClass, instead of using the code in the sample you showed, you could use...

```
Intent i = new Intent("PopupClass.class");
startActivityForResult(i);
```

When the PopupClass activity is finished it can set return data in another Intent and finish.

Then in the ActivityClass you override `onActivityResult(...)` and process the returned Intent.